# SLURM: Run programs in another node

Tags: linux, slurm

I've just finished the SLURM installation in our cluster. How do I run programs in node2 (slave) from node1 (head/controller node)? Is there a special configuration for this kind of setup?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that UIDs are uniform across the cluster nodes, and that a common filesystem (for instance NFS) is mounted on all nodes.

Then you run programs typically by submitting jobs with the `sbatch` command.

You can refer to this [set of slides](http://www.ceci-hpc.be/assets/training/slurm.pdf) for a quick start.